# What to say when I want to ensure something is right?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-construction, spoken-english

Sometimes, when I am engaging a conversation with somebody and I want to make sure a statement is correct, I would (almost always) say

> So ...(a statement based on what the other person just said)..., right/is it correct?

Are there any other ways to phrase this sentence? I personally find that native speakers seldom use this sentence.

Comment: I'd encourage you to edit this question and add a few examples to give us a better idea of what kind of statements you are talking about. There are many kinds of assertions ranging from scientific facts to matters of opinion. Consider, for example, _"The only even prime number is 2,"_ or, _"We are meeting at the restaurant at 6PM,"_ or, _"Michael Jordan was he greatest basketball player of all time."_ I might look to verify those in slightly different ways.

Comment: Adding "...right?" at the end of a sentence is kind of a meaningless filler word that doesn't really ask for confirmation.  Some people even use it like "So I was walking down the street, right?  And I see my old friend Tom, right?"  Saying "__ ____ ____, is it correct?" sounds very non-fluent because that's not how you make a question in English.  I would suggest something like, "If I understand correctly, ____ ____ ____.  Is that correct?"

Comment: @stangdon Hmmm, well... I think the "filler" status of _right?_ is very much context-dependent. See e.g. _"So, in a right triangle, the square on the hypotenuse is equal to the sum of the squares on the other two sides, right?"_ or _"We're leaving at eight o'clock, right?"_ In both of those, _right_ is an unequivocal request for confirmation. I think _right?_ is the most idiomatic of ways to express what Nicholas wants here. (Don't know why he would think that native speakers "seldom use this sentence". I hear it more than any other in this situation.)

Comment: Oh really? Then maybe because native speakers seldom misunderstand others and need to ensure something, I guess.@P.E.Dant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it's *ensure* something is right (not *assure*).  To assure means "to dispel doubts", while "ensure" means "to make certain".

Since it's not entirely clear what you are trying to say, here are some examples of both:

> How can I assure you that (some statement) is correct?
>
> How do I ensure that (some statement) is correct?
>
> I want to assure you that (some statement) is correct?
>
> I need to ensure that (some statement) is correct.

If this is confusing, remember you *assure* some person(s), and *ensure* some process or action.

Then of course there's "to *insure*" -- but you should probably just read this:  [Assure vs. Ensure vs. Insure](http://data.grammarbook.com/blog/definitions/assure-vs-ensure-vs-insure/)

Comment: Thanks, Andrew. I think the word I'd like to use is *ensure*, not *assure*. Now for instance, if one would like to know how rent is paid, whether monthly/annually (let's say I am negotiating with a subleaser), should one say "A: How do I ensure that the rent is paid monthly? B: Yes, it's collected monthly."

Comment: It seems strange to me since I think it's a yes-or-no question, but the question, as you sugested goes with word *How*.

Comment: @Nicholas yes that's exactly right.  "How do I ensure the rent is due monthly?"   If it's yes/no then it would be "Can I ensure that the rent is due monthly?" or some similar question.

Comment: Okay, if one asks "Can I ensure that the rent is due monthly?", I can reply "Yes, it is." or "No, it's due annually." But how would one reply "How do I ensure the rent is due monthly?"? BTW, *due* is literally more idiomatic to me than the passive structure "is paid" I used:)

Comment: @Nicholas - I wouldn't use _ensure_, I would use _know_ or _find out_. "How can I know if the rent is due monthly?"

Comment: @Nicholas it's kind of an odd question, but the answer would be something like "Here, look at the rental agreement".   At some point you're forcing a word into a sentence instead of (as J.R. says) using a more natural phrase like "make sure" or "guarantee", or even rewriting it to a way that makes more sense (in English).  "The rent is paid monthly, yes? Can I get that *in writing*?"